# How can I attach a persistent EBS volume to an EC2 Linux launch template that is used in an autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ebs, mounted-volumes

To Clarify my Autoscaling group removes all instances and their root EBS volumes during inactive hours, then once inside active hours recreates and installs all necessary base programs. However I have a smaller EBS volume that is persistent and holds code and data I do not want getting wiped out during down times. I am currently manually attaching via the console and mounting every time I am working inside active hours using the commands below.

```
sudo mkdir userVolume
sudo mount /dev/xvdf userVolume
```

How can I automatically attach and mount this volume to a folder? This is all for the sake of minimizing cost and uptime to when I can actually be working on it.

Comment: Where do you attach this EBS? To one of the autoscaling node? Or is this is the root volume?

Comment: I am currently attaching it to the EC2 instance generated via the autoscaling group. If there is a better way to incorporate it into the file system I would be fine with that.

Comment: You could use a User Data script on the instance so that it attaches the persistent EBS Volume to itself by using AWS CLI to attach the volume, then the commands you show to mount the volume. Alternatively, you could create an Amazon EFS filesystem, which is a network storage system. You can then mount the network filesystem to the instance.

Comment: Do you mean this?
aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-1234567890abcdef0 --instance-id i-01474ef662b89480 --device /dev/sdf
The issue with this command is it needs the instance ID which is different every time the instance is rebuilt, is there a way to reference my current id?

Comment: If the code and data remains the same and doesn't change with autoscaling nodes, why not include it in the autoscaling image? The better solution in this case is EFS as suggested by John. As for the instance id, you can get instance id by running `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`.

Comment: I don't think I can store and run code from EFS though, can a Java project or JAR be placed in EFS and ran? Thanks for the curl!

Comment: Downloading from s3 to local when the node is up is not an option either? Also why not include it in the base image? This way, the autoscalign nodes will be created with the data already present.

Comment: Hmm, I will have to look into the S3 option as it might be cheaper than a small persistent EBS volume. This EC2 instance is more for my tinkering and education than a fixed purpose updating an AMI over and over with test code and programs seems like it would be very manual? I am not sure on this. My instance is up and down a few times during the day for hours when I can work on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
      OUTPUT=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
      aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-xxxxxxxxxxxx --device /dev/xvdf --instance-id $OUTPUT --region ap-southeast-1
```

Set your volume ID and region.

Refer this link for further details: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-spot-instance-attach-ebs-volume/

Comment: unfortunately adding this to my init script with the values replaced did not work. not attached or linked

Comment: Did you check the log to see what the problem was? You can also ssh to the machine and try running the command to ensure it is working. A few things to note: 1. the machine needs to have correct role / permissions; 2. Ensure correct region in the command. Hope this helps.

Comment: Here is my boot script am I doing something wrong?

#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y 
sudo yum install java-17.0.1-openjdk -y
sudo yum install python37 python37-pip
sudo mkdir /home/userVolume
OUTPUT=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
sudo aws ec2 attach-volume --volume-id vol-[REDACTED] --device /dev/xvdf --instance-id $OUTPUT --region us-east-2

Comment: I don't think you need to use `sudo` as this script already runs as root. Have you checked logs (look for cloud init logs) to see if you got any errors? Also, run this command in shell after machine is setup to ensure it works (this will confirm if you have required permissions).